# How to check connectivity of apns port 2195 from my hosting server?

Tags: shared-hosting, apple-push-notifications

I want to check if Push Notification can be done using a hosting server before purchasing hosting plan.what is the shortest way to check this.Also i have godaddy.com's hosting plan can i use push notification from godaddy's hosting server?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can confirm definitively by using telnet and specifying which port to connect to.  From the command line run:

```
MyServer:~ Home$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.143...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If there is an error connecting then it will just hang and not return - the above shows a working example where I can connect.

You'll need an SSH login to your hosting service to test it this way, and unfortunately you are unlikely to be able to test it without buying an account - so you probably have to rely on asking their customer services.

Be aware that basic hosting packages normally just provide an FTP login to let you serve up files, you'll usually have to pay extra to get a hosting package which provides SSH access (which you'll need if you are going to run code to connect to the Apple Push Notification Servers).

Comment: Hey there. I had a similar problem. Sending push messages did work locally but not on our test server. This helped me trouble shoot the problem very effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Could anybody tell me the whole process to open port 2195 on my hosting server ........@Besi,@Dan J

Comment: Please post that as a separate question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

if your system does not have telnet, you can make use of curl to do the job.

```
curl -v telnet://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

here -v is for verbose output

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Curl if telnet command is not available.
curl -v telnet://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195/
*   Trying 17.188.137.190...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com (17.188.137.190) port 2195 (#0)

Press Escape to close the connection
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with GoDaddy. Amazon Web Services did the trick for me. It allows you to easily deploy a PHP script which can be called anywhere on the web.

Answer (score -2):

I just purchased my Godaddy account to find out it blocks all connections except 80 and one other. In other words we can't use the 2195 connection that is required. If you find another one please let me know.

Comment: @Bryan godaddy service is not so good but you can use urabnairship.com it's free for 10000 push messages.try this out with your godaddy hosting for more information log on to urabnairship.com

Comment: I assume Rahul is referring to urbanairship.com