# Apple push notification not received

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am not receiving the push notification on device. When I run the webservice I do not get any error the connection happens properly. I checked the ports also, but they are also open. I am using php for webservice and GoDaddy server. When I try from other server keeping other files same I receive the push notification on device but when I use our server neither push notification is received nor any error is received. Will I have to something with certificate, if so how will I have to do that? Please help

Comment: Ever found a solution to this? I use GoDaddy too but don't receive any notifications. Though I haven't tried from another server but the php script doesn't show any issues. It says connection went through fine!

Comment: We searched on it, but were not able to get solution. GoDaddy server cannot be used for push notification as when we tried another server all worked fine.

Comment: I got it working with the godaddy server after putting in the pem files. the problem was not godaddy. it was the pem files.

Answer (score 1):

please check this tutorial [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/)

First, if its all perfect then check that your [port 2195](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4264) must be open if its not open then send a request to your domain service provider to open it. [How to check 2195 work or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811919/how-to-check-connectivity-of-apns-port-2195-from-my-hosting-server)